# nbtstat command

Tags: command

I'm trying to run:

```
$ nbtstat -a 192.168.183.147
bash: nbtstat: command not found
```

and:

```
$ sudo nbtstat -a 192.168.183.147
bash: nbtstat: command not found
```

does anyone know why I'm getting this error message? Once! I just instated nbtstat tools.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

[nbtstat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nbtstat) is a windows command.

`nmblookup` may be an alternative to `nbtstat`, it can be installed through:

```
sudo apt install samba-common-bin
```

[manpages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmblookup.1.html) ( `man nmblookup`):

```
   nmblookup - NetBIOS over TCP/IP client used to lookup NetBIOS names
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked.

Comment: @user377346 please remember to accept this answer, since it worked best for you

Answer (score 1):

To be precise in addition to the answer GAD3R gave, the exact command to get similar output is `nmblookup -A <ip_address>`